# Overplot image with ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, image-processing

I have (x,y) data here: http://pastebin.com/raw/NUNC5Jb2

Now I would like to overplot a `ListLinePlot` of this data on top of an `image`:

[image]

I did the following:

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/NUNC5Jb2"];

{minx, maxx} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]];
{miny, maxy} = MinMax[data[[All, 2]]];

ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}}, 
 AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@image, 
 PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, Frame -> True, 
 Prolog -> {Texture[image], 
   Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
     Scaled[{0, 1}]}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Ticks -> None]
```

The result is:

[image]

Does also another solution exists?

Comment: You can replace your prolog with `Prolog->{Inset[image, Sequence @@ (ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}})]}` which is slightly less verbose. Is there anything in particular you're looking for?

Comment: and even *slightly* less verbose than the above would be `Prolog -> Inset[image, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]`

Comment: @Jason B. This command shows a small gap at right and upper part between image and axes. When I modify it to `Prolog -> {Inset[image, Scaled[{.5, .5}], Automatic, Scaled[1]]}]`
 then the gaps vanish.

Comment: @mrz I used an `ImagePadding -> None` and it seemed to be the same as your plot